# Getting a CORBS error when using remote images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I'm getting this error in my console when a pass down an online image url as props.
My app basically pulls data from an excel sheet and I'm passing that data down as props (if I get the image from local storage, the image loads correctly). I have added screenshots to describe all these.

I have tried looking through chrome documentation on this. I can see it's a security measure but I cannot seem to resolve this.

Edit: error message is

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
> https://drive.google.com/file/d/16PCFlaC0fvsCzpnOxFJiS2uWJvuSkjTn/view?usp=sharing
> with MIME type text/html. See
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
> details.

[image: Image description]

[image: Image description]

[image: Image description]

Comment: Please include errors as text within the question not (rather low resolution) images.

Comment: My bad @phuzi I have added an edit with the error message.

Comment: Opening that link in the browser opens a full page and not just the image! You're going to have to find a way of getting just the image - with the proper MIME type. Drive probably isn't supposed to be used this way!